# Error pulling menus wordpress typescript react nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm starting in react with typescript and I must be making a mistake, in typing, I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
import React from 'react'
import { NextPage } from 'next'

interface HeaderProps {
  menu: Array<{
    title: string
    url: string
  }>
}

const Header: NextPage<HeaderProps> = (props: HeaderProps) => {
...
```

I'm trying to pull menus from Wordpress

```
Header.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost/wp-json/myroutes/menu')
  const json = await res.json()
  return {
    props: {
      menu: json
    }
  }
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

So for this, assuming this is still an issue you're grappling with, you can use a query with a fragment like so to get the data externally from headless wordpress (highly advise you use the WP-GraphQL plugin)

```
fragment DynamicNavFragment on WordpressMenuItem {
    id
    label
    path
    parentId
}
```

Then for the query, you import the fragment using a `#` at the top of the file:

```
# import DynamicNavFragment from '../Partials/dynamic-nav-fields.graphql'

query DynamicNav(
    $idHead: ID!
    $idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum!
    $idFoot: ID!
    $idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum!
) {
    Header: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idHead, idType: $idTypeHead) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                    childItems {
                                        edges {
                                            node {
                                                ...DynamicNavFragment
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Footer: wordpress {
        menu(id: $idFoot, idType: $idTypeFoot) {
            menuItems(where: { parentId: 0 }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ...DynamicNavFragment
                        childItems {
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    ...DynamicNavFragment
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To generate type definitions from this code, us a codegen.yml file as follows:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema:
  ${ONEGRAPH_API_URL_YML}:
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer ${WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_YML}
documents: 'graphql/**/*.graphql'
generates:
  graphql/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - typescript:
          constEnums: false
          enumsAsTypes: false          
          numericEnums: false
          namingConvention: keep
          futureProofEnums: false
          enumsAsConst: false
          onlyOperationTypes: false
          maybeValue: T | null | undefined
          noExport: false
          enumPrefix: true
          fieldWrapperValue: T
          wrapFieldDefinitions: true
          skipTypename: false
          nonOptionalTypename: false
          useTypeImports: false
          avoidOptionals: true
          declarationKind: 
            input: interface
            type: interface
      - typescript-operations:
          declarationKind:
            input: interface
            type: interface
          avoidOptionals: true
          exportFragmentSpreadSubTypes: true
      - typescript-react-apollo:
          addDocBlocks: true
          reactApolloVersion: 3
          documentMode: documentNodeImportFragments
    config:
      maybeValue: T | null | undefined
      declarationKind:
       input: interface
       type: interface
      documentNodeImportFragments: true
      reactApolloVersion: 3
      withHooks: true
      numericEnums: false
      namingConvention: keep
      withHOC: false
      avoidOptionals: true
      withComponent: false
      exportFragmentSpreadSubTypes: true
      addDocBlocks: true
  graphql/graphql.schema.graphql:
    plugins:
      - schema-ast
    config:
      commentDescriptions: true
  graphql/graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - introspection
    config:
      commentDescriptions: true
      
hooks:
  afterAllFileWrite: 
    - prettier --write
```

This goes down several layers to get sub-paths and sub-sub-paths dynamically injected in the nav (header). Now for using the data itself, I can include my navbar + dynamic nav and layout components. It is a bit of code, but map through it and you'll follow along (this is all nextjs+typescript)

headless-navbar.tsx

```
import { useState, FC, useRef, Fragment } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Transition, Listbox } from '@headlessui/react';
import { NavArrow } from '@/components/UI/Icons';
import { DynamicNavQuery } from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';
import css from './headless-navbar.module.css';
import { DynamicNavDissected } from '@/types/dynamic-nav';

export interface HeadlessNavbarProps
    extends DynamicNavDissected {
    header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
    className?: string;
}

const HeadlessNavbar: FC<HeadlessNavbarProps> = ({
    header,
    className,
    node
}) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [subOpen, setSubOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(node);
    const { pathname } = useRouter();
    const refAcceptor = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

    return (
        <>
            {header != null &&
            header.menu != null &&
            header.menu.menuItems != null &&
            header.menu.menuItems.edges != null &&
            header.menu.menuItems.edges.length > 0 ? (
                header.menu.menuItems.edges.map((top, i) => {
                    return top != null &&
                        top.node != null &&
                        top.node.label != null ? (
                        <>
                            <Link
                                href={top.node.path}
                                as={top.node.path}
                                passHref
                                scroll={true}
                                key={top.node.id}
                            >
                                <a
                                    id='top'
                                    className={cn(className, {
                                        [css.active]: pathname === top.node.path,
                                        [css.link]: pathname !== top.node.path
                                    })}
                                >
                                    <p>{top.node.label}</p>
                                </a>
                            </Link>
                            {top.node.childItems != null &&
                            top.node.childItems.edges != null &&
                            top.node.childItems.edges.length > 0 ? (
                                <div className='relative z-150 -ml-2'>
                                    <button
                                        onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
                                        id='sub-menu'
                                        aria-haspopup={true}
                                        aria-expanded={true}
                                        type='button'
                                        className={cn(css.topButton, {
                                            'lg:-translate-x-4 ring-secondary-0 ring-1 rotate-0': isOpen,
                                            'lg:-translate-x-5 ring-redditNav ring-0 -rotate-90': !isOpen
                                        })}
                                    >
                                        <NavArrow className='select-none lg:w-5 lg:h-5' />
                                    </button>
                                    <Transition
                                        show={isOpen}
                                        enter='transition ease-out duration-200 '
                                        enterFrom='transform opacity-0 translate-y-1'
                                        enterTo='transform opacity-100 translate-y-0'
                                        leave='transition ease-in duration-150'
                                        leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 translate-y-0'
                                        leaveTo='transform opacity-0 translate-y-1'
                                    >
                                        <div className={cn(css.transitionAlpha, '')}>
                                            <div
                                                className={css.transitionBeta}
                                                ref={refAcceptor}
                                                role='menu'
                                                aria-orientation='vertical'
                                                aria-labelledby='sub-menu'
                                            >
                                                <div className={css.transitionGamma}>
                                                    {top!.node!.childItems!.edges!.map((sub, j) => {
                                                        return sub != null &&
                                                            sub.node != null &&
                                                            sub.node.label != null &&
                                                            sub.node.parentId != null ? (
                                                            <Listbox
                                                                key={sub.node.id}
                                                                value={selectedCategory}
                                                                onChange={setSelectedCategory}
                                                            >
                                                                {({ open }) => (
                                                                    <>
                                                                        <div className={cn(css.divOpen)}>
                                                                            <p className='text-lg'>{sub!.node!.label!}</p>
                                                                            <Listbox.Button
                                                                                aria-haspopup={true}
                                                                                id='sub'
                                                                                aria-expanded={true}
                                                                                onClick={() => setSubOpen(!subOpen)}
                                                                                className={cn(css.topButton, {
                                                                                    'lg:-translate-x-4 ring-secondary-0 ring-1 rotate-0': open,
                                                                                    'lg:-translate-x-5 ring-redditSearch ring-0 -rotate-90': !open
                                                                                })}
                                                                            >
                                                                                <NavArrow className='select-none lg:w-5 lg:h-5' />
                                                                            </Listbox.Button>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <Transition
                                                                            show={open}
                                                                            enter='transition ease-out duration-100'
                                                                            enterFrom='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                                                                            enterTo='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                                                                            leave='transition ease-in duration-75'
                                                                            leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                                                                            leaveTo='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                                                                        >
                                                                            <Listbox.Options
                                                                                static
                                                                                className='outline-none select-none focus:outline-none'
                                                                            >
                                                                                {sub!.node!.childItems != null &&
                                                                                sub!.node!.childItems.edges != null &&
                                                                                sub!.node!.childItems.edges.length > 0 ? (
                                                                                    sub!.node!.childItems!.edges!.map(
                                                                                        (subsub, k) => {
                                                                                            return subsub != null &&
                                                                                                subsub.node != null &&
                                                                                                subsub.node.label != null &&
                                                                                                subsub.node.parentId != null ? (
                                                                                                <>
                                                                                                    {open && (
                                                                                                        <Listbox.Option
                                                                                                            key={subsub.node.id}
                                                                                                            className={cn(
                                                                                                                css.subsub,
                                                                                                                'text-base font-medium list-none outline-none'
                                                                                                            )}
                                                                                                            value={subsub!.node!.label}
                                                                                                        >
                                                                                                            <>
                                                                                                                <Link
                                                                                                                    href={subsub!.node!.path}
                                                                                                                    passHref
                                                                                                                    key={k++}
                                                                                                                >
                                                                                                                    <a
                                                                                                                        id='subsub'
                                                                                                                        className={cn(css.subsubanchor)}
                                                                                                                        key={subsub!.node!.id}
                                                                                                                    >
                                                                                                                        {subsub!.node!.label}
                                                                                                                    </a>
                                                                                                                </Link>
                                                                                                            </>
                                                                                                        </Listbox.Option>
                                                                                                    )}
                                                                                                </>
                                                                                            ) : (
                                                                                                <></>
                                                                                            );
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    )
                                                                                ) : (
                                                                                    <></>
                                                                                )}
                                                                            </Listbox.Options>
                                                                        </Transition>
                                                                    </>
                                                                )}
                                                            </Listbox>
                                                        ) : (
                                                            <></>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </Transition>
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <></>
                            )}
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default HeadlessNavbar;
```

NOTE: `DynamicNavDissected` is defined in the `@/types` directory as follows

```
import {
    Maybe,
    DynamicNavFragmentFragment
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';

export interface DynamicNavDissected {
    node?: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem' } & {
            childItems: Maybe<
                {
                    __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnection';
                } & {
                    edges: Maybe<
                        Array<
                            Maybe<
                                {
                                    __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItemToMenuItemConnectionEdge';
                                } & {
                                    node: Maybe<
                                        {
                                            __typename?: 'WordpressMenuItem';
                                        } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
                                    >;
                                }
                            >
                        >
                    >;
                }
            >;
        } & DynamicNavFragmentFragment
    >;
}
```

headless-navbar.module.css

```css
.active {
    @apply p-2 rounded-md text-base text-secondary-0 font-bold 2xl:text-lg 2xl:tracking-tight;
    &:hover {
        @apply text-opacity-75 transition-opacity transform-gpu duration-300;
    }
}
.link {
    @apply p-2 rounded-md text-base text-secondary-0 font-semibold 2xl:text-lg 2xl:tracking-tight;
    &:hover {
        @apply text-opacity-75 transition-opacity transform-gpu duration-300;
    }
}

.topButton {
    @apply bg-redditNav rounded-full flex ml-4 items-center my-auto text-secondary-0 transition-transform transform-gpu ease-in-out duration-200 outline-none md:py-0 lg:ml-0 lg:mx-auto;
    &:focus {
        @apply outline-none;
    }
}

.bottomButton {
    @apply bg-redditSearch rounded-full inline-flex ml-4 items-center my-auto text-secondary-0 transition-transform transform-gpu ease-in-out delay-200 duration-200 outline-none md:py-0 lg:ml-0 lg:mx-auto;
    &:focus {
        @apply outline-none;
    }
}

.subsub p {
    @apply ml-10 !important;
}

.transitionAlpha {
    @apply relative z-150 -ml-4 mt-3 transform px-2 w-screen max-w-sm sm:px-0 lg:absolute lg:ml-0 lg:left-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2 lg:mx-auto;
}

.transitionBeta {
    @apply flex-grow rounded-lg ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden lg:shadow-lg lg:ring-1 lg:ring-black;
}

.transitionGamma {
    @apply relative grid bg-redditSearch text-secondary-0 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8 lg:flex-col lg:gap-3 lg:py-6 transition-transform transform-gpu;
}

.subanchor {
    @apply -m-1 p-3 flex items-start rounded-md lg:-m-3;
    &:hover {
        @apply bg-redditNav;
    }
}

.subsubanchor {
    @apply -m-1 p-3 flex items-start rounded-md lg:-m-3 lg:ml-2;
    &:hover {
        @apply bg-redditNav;
    }
}

.subtosubsub {
    @apply relative px-5 bg-redditSearch text-secondary-0 flex-grow sm:gap-8 lg:gap-3;
}

.divOpen {
    @apply grid grid-cols-3 w-full min-w-full transition-transform ease-in-out duration-300 transform-gpu;
}
```

Now, for the Navbar component into which the headless-navbar data is injected -- I use two separate sites to inject Desktop vs Mobile dynamic nav respectively. Confers more granular control + separation of concerns

navbar.tsx

```
import { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import NavbarLinks from './navbar-links';
import css from './navbar.module.css';
import { Transition } from '@headlessui/react/dist';
import { Logo } from '../../UI';
import Link from 'next/link';
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle';
import MenuIcon from '../../UI/Icons/menu-icon';
import XIcon from '../../UI/Icons/x-icon';

interface NavbarProps {
    root?: string;
    Desktop?: React.ReactNode;
    Mobile?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Navbar: FC<NavbarProps> = ({ root, Desktop, Mobile }) => {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(true);
    const [isOpen] = useState(false);
    const [hasScrolled, setHasScrolled] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = throttle(() => {
            const offset = 0;
            const { scrollTop } = document.documentElement;
            const scrolled = scrollTop > offset;
            setHasScrolled(scrolled);
        }, 200);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, [hasScrolled]);
    return (
        <>
            <nav className={cn(root, css.root, css.stickyNav)}>
                <div
                    className={cn(
                        css.stickyNav,
                        { 'shadow-magical': hasScrolled },
                        'max-w-full mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 font-sans text-secondary-0 transform-gpu duration-500 ease-in-out transition-all'
                    )}
                >
                    <div
                        className={cn(
                            'flex flex-row-reverse justify-between transform-gpu duration-500 ease-in-out transition-all',
                            css.stickyNav,
                            {
                                'h-24': !hasScrolled,
                                'h-20': hasScrolled
                            }
                        )}
                    >
                        <div className='flex'>
                            <div className='-ml-2 mr-2 flex items-center lg:hidden w-full min-w-full'>
                                <button
                                    className='inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-secondary-0 hover:text-opacity-80 hover:bg-opacity-80 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-secondary-0'
                                    aria-expanded={false}
                                    onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}
                                >
                                    <span className='sr-only'>Open Main Menu</span>
                                    {menuOpen ? (
                                        <MenuIcon
                                            className={cn('h-8 w-8 focus:outline-none', {
                                                hidden: !menuOpen,
                                                block: menuOpen
                                            })}
                                        />
                                    ) : (
                                        <XIcon
                                            className={cn('h-8 w-8 focus:outline-none', {
                                                hidden: menuOpen,
                                                block: !menuOpen
                                            })}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='hidden lg:ml-6 lg:flex lg:items-center lg:space-x-4'>
                                {Desktop ?? <NavbarLinks />}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex items-center'>
                            <div className='flex-shrink-0'>
                                <div className='lg:mx-4 lg:flex-shrink-0 lg:flex lg:items-center'>
                                    <div className='ml-3 '>
                                        <div className=''>
                                            <span className='sr-only'>The Faderoom Inc.</span>
                                            <Link href='/' passHref scroll={true}>
                                                <a className='#logo'>
                                                    <Logo
                                                        className={cn(
                                                            css.svg,
                                                            'cursor-default focus:outline-none transition-all transform-gpu ease-in-out duration-500',
                                                            {
                                                                'w-18 h-18': !hasScrolled,
                                                                'w-14 h-14': hasScrolled
                                                            }
                                                        )}
                                                    />
                                                </a>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                        <Transition
                                            show={isOpen && !hasScrolled}
                                        >
                                            <Transition.Child
                                                enter='transition ease-out duration-200'
                                                enterFrom='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                                                enterTo='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                                                leave='transition ease-in duration-200'
                                                leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                                                leaveTo='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                                            >
                                                <div
                                                    role='menu'
                                                    aria-orientation='vertical'
                                                    aria-labelledby='user-menu'
                                                    className={
                                                        'origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 h-40 w-44 rounded-md shadow-lg ring-2 ring-red-900 outline-none grid grid-cols-1 bg-secondary-0 z-50 px-3 py-2 hover:bg-opacity-80'
                                                    }
                                                >
                                                    <NavbarLinks
                                                        root={cn('px-3 py-2 hover:bg-secondary-0')}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </Transition.Child>
                                        </Transition>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    className={cn('lg:hidden text-secondary-0', {
                        block: !menuOpen,
                        hidden: menuOpen
                    })}
                >
                    <div className='px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3 align-middle'>
                        {Mobile ?? (
                            <NavbarLinks
                                root={cn(
                                    'block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-2xl font-medium text-secondary-0'
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

navbar.module.css

```css
.epiRoot {
    @apply sticky top-0 bg-black z-40 transition-all duration-150;
}

.root {
    @apply bg-redditNav select-none;
}

.svg {
    z-index: 100;
    @apply block sm:content-center sm:mx-auto;
}

.stickyNav {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    transition: 0.1 ease-in-out;
    &.root {
        transition: 0.1 ease-in-out;
    }
}

.navLinks div > a {
    @apply text-lg lg:text-xl;
}
```

#### Now for the global layout, and lastly the index page to illustrate how to use apollo with getStaticProps

layout.tsx

```
import { FooterFixture } from './Footer';
import { HeadlessFooter } from './HeadlessFooter';
import { HeadlessNavbar } from './HeadlessNavbar';
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';
import { Meta } from './Meta';
import cn from 'classnames';
import {
    DynamicNavQuery,
    useDynamicNavQuery,
    WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';
import {
    ApolloError,
    Button,
    Fallback,
    Modal,
    LandingHero
} from '../UI';
import { useGlobal } from '../Context';
import { useAcceptCookies } from '@/lib/use-accept-cookies';
import Head from 'next/head';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const dynamicProps = {
    loading: () => <Fallback />
};

const LoginView = dynamic(
    () => import('../Auth/wp-login-holder'),
    dynamicProps
);

const Featurebar = dynamic(
    () => import('./Featurebar'),
    dynamicProps
);

export interface LayoutProps {
    Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
    Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
    className?: string;
    title?: string;
    hero?: React.ReactNode;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

function AppLayout({
    Header,
    Footer,
    className,
    title,
    children,
    hero
}: LayoutProps) {
    const { acceptedCookies, onAcceptCookies } = useAcceptCookies();
    const { displayModal, modalView, closeModal } = useGlobal();
    const { loading, error, data } = useDynamicNavQuery({
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
    });
    const router = useRouter();
    Header =
        data != null && data.Header != null ? data.Header : undefined;
    Footer =
        data != null && data.Footer != null ? data.Footer : undefined;

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{title ?? '✂ The Fade Room Inc. ✂'}</title>
            </Head>
            <Meta />
            {error ? (
                <>
                    <ApolloError error={error} />
                </>
            ) : loading && !error ? (
                <Fallback />
            ) : (
                <Navbar
                    Desktop={<HeadlessNavbar header={Header} />}
                    Mobile={
                        <HeadlessNavbar
                            header={Header}
                            className={
                                'block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-semibold text-secondary-0 hover:bg-redditSearch'
                            }
                        />
                    }
                />
            )}
            <>
                {router.pathname === '/' ? <LandingHero /> : hero}
                <Modal open={displayModal} onClose={closeModal}>
                    {modalView === 'LOGIN_VIEW' && <LoginView />}
                </Modal>
                <div className={cn('bg-redditSearch min-h-full', className)}>
                    <main className='fit min-h-full'>{children}</main>
                    {error ? (
                        <>
                            <ApolloError error={error} />
                        </>
                    ) : loading && !error ? (
                        <Fallback />
                    ) : (
                        <FooterFixture
                            children={<HeadlessFooter footer={Footer} />}
                        />
                    )}

                    <div className='font-sans z-150'>
                        <Featurebar
                            title='This site uses cookies to improve your experience. By clicking, you agree to our Privacy Policy.'
                            hide={acceptedCookies}
                            className='prose-lg sm:prose-xl bg-opacity-90 sm:text-center'
                            action={
                                <Button
                                    type='submit'
                                    variant='slim'
                                    className='mx-auto text-secondary-0 text-center rounded-xl border-secondary-0 border-1 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-opacity-80 hover:border-secondary-0 duration-500 ease-in-out transform-gpu transition-colors'
                                    onClick={() => onAcceptCookies()}
                                >
                                    Accept Cookies
                                </Button>
                            }
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        </>
    );
}

export default AppLayout;
```

pages/index.tsx -- apollo client implicitly passes in props indicated by `GetStaticPropsResult`(their respective queries are also present). `reviews` is not handled by apolloclient but by a fetching method, so it has to be explicitly passed in

```
import { initializeApollo, addApolloState } from '@/lib/apollo';
import { AppLayout } from '@/components/Layout';
import {
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    GetStaticPropsResult,
    InferGetStaticPropsType
} from 'next';
import {
    LandingDataQuery,
    LandingDataQueryVariables,
    LandingDataDocument,
    DynamicNavDocument,
    DynamicNavQueryVariables,
    DynamicNavQuery,
    WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';
import { LandingCoalesced } from '@/components/Landing';
import { BooksyReviews } from '@/components/Landing/Booksy';
import { getLatestBooksyReviews } from '@/lib/booksy';
import { BooksyReviewFetchResponse } from '@/types/booksy';
import {
    useWordpressLoginMutation,
    WordpressLoginMutation,
    WordpressLoginMutationVariables,
    WordpressLoginDocument
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';

export function Index({
    other,
    popular,
    Header,
    Footer,
    places,
    businessHours,
    reviews
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
    return (
        <>
            <AppLayout
                title={'✂ The Fade Room Inc. ✂'}
                Header={Header}
                Footer={Footer}
            >
                <LandingCoalesced
                    other={other}
                    popular={popular}
                    places={places}
                    businessHours={businessHours}
                >
                    <BooksyReviews reviews={reviews.reviews} />
                </LandingCoalesced>
            </AppLayout>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<{
        other: LandingDataQuery['other'];
        popular: LandingDataQuery['popular'];
        places: LandingDataQuery['Places'];
        businessHours: LandingDataQuery['businessHours'];
        Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
        Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
        reviews: BooksyReviewFetchResponse;
        // Context: WordpressLoginMutation;
    }>
> {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    await apolloClient.query<
        DynamicNavQuery,
        DynamicNavQueryVariables
    >({
        query: DynamicNavDocument,
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        }
    });

    await apolloClient.query<
        LandingDataQuery,
        LandingDataQueryVariables
    >({
        query: LandingDataDocument,
        variables: {
            other: 'all',
            popular: 'popular-service',
            path: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PLACES_PATH!,
            googleMapsKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY!
        }
    });

    const response = await getLatestBooksyReviews();
    const reviews: BooksyReviewFetchResponse = await response.json();

    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {
            reviews
        },
        revalidate: 60
    });
}
export default Index;
```

For the sake of thoroughness, here is my `@/lib/apollo.ts` file

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    NormalizedCacheObject,
    HttpLink
} from '@apollo/client';
import {
    getAccessToken,
    getAccessTokenAsCookie
} from './cookies';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import type {
    PersistentContext,
    CookieOptions
} from '@/types/index';
import { getCookiesFromContext } from '@/utils/regex-parsing';
import {
    WORDPRESS_USER_COOKIE_EXPIRE,
    WORDPRESS_USER_TOKEN_COOKIE
} from './const';

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__';

let apolloClient:
    | ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>
    | undefined;

function createApolloClient(
    options?: CookieOptions
): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    const authLink = setContext((_, { ...headers }: Headers) => {
        const token =
            getAccessToken(options) ?? getAccessTokenAsCookie(options);
        if (!token) {
            return {};
        }
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'X-JWT-REFRESH': `Bearer ${process.env
                    .WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN!}`,
                'x-jwt-auth': token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
            }
        };
    });
    const httpLink = new HttpLink({
        uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONEGRAPH_API_URL}`,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        ...(typeof window !== undefined && { fetch })
    });
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
            typePolicies: {
                Query: {
                    fields: {
                        wordpress: {
                            merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
                                // Invoking nested merge functions
                                return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
                            }
                        },
                        google: {
                            merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
                                // Invoking nested merge functions
                                return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
}

export function initializeApollo(
    initialState: any | any = null,
    context?: PersistentContext
) {
    const _apolloClient =
        apolloClient ??
        createApolloClient({
            cookies: getCookiesFromContext(
                context ?? WORDPRESS_USER_TOKEN_COOKIE
            )
        });
    // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
    // gets hydrated here
    if (initialState) {
        // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();
        // Merge the existing cache into data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
        const data = { ...existingCache, ...initialState };
        // const data = deepmerge(initialState, existingCache, { clone: false });
        // Restore the cache with the merged data
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data);
    }
    // for SSG and SSR ALWAYS create a new Apollo Client
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;
    // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;
    return _apolloClient;
}

export function addApolloState(client: any, pageProps: any) {
    if (pageProps?.props) {
        pageProps.props[
            APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME
        ] = client.cache.extract();
    }
    return pageProps;
}

export function useApollo(pageProps: any) {
    const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME];
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state]);
    return store;
}
```